# How do I check if a UIViewController class is defined as part of SDK or is user-defined?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to check if a given UIViewController is user-defined or system provided?

```
//The following may be implemented in one of the View Controller lifecycle methods by swizzling
NSString *controllerName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
if([Helper controllerIsUserDefined:controllerName]) {
     //Let us do this only for user-defined UIViewController classes
}
```

I'm looking for a way to implement `controllerIsUserDefined` method. Also I don't prefer adding dummy properties or methods to user-defined ViewController classes and then check using `respondsToSelector` since this functionality might be used in existing project as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a class is defined in the main bundle and that may solve your problem.

```
if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] isEqual:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]]) {
    // Object class defined in the main bundle
}
```

This may not work if the class is defined in a user supplied framework.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. This works well for me, I'm not expecting any user supplied framework to be playing a role in my use case.